# Export Sql Server (64 bit) to Excel (32 bit)

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel, sql-server-2014

I tried to export data from SQL Server to excel, but it does not work.

My code is

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;
Database=D:\FATXL.xlsx;', 
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
 SELECT * FROM tabel1
```

Error

> The 32-bit OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be 
>       loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server.

I need to know if its possible  to export data from   64 bit SQL Server to  32 bit MS Excel and how to do it?

Should we have same bit of SQL server and excel for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Here's are some alternative solutions which never fail.

**Alternative solution 1**

**Caveat:** You'd need to run this query manually in the SSMS.

Use Export to save you results in a CSV file which can be opened in Excel and saves as XLS.

[image]

[image]

**Alternative solution 2**

**Caveat:** You'd need to run this query manually in the SSMS.

You can change the Query results display options from grid to file which can be a CSV file and also check the `SET NO COUNT` option like below
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Alternative solution 3**

**Caveat:** Once again need SSMS

Go to Database name and right click to select `Tasks> Export` from menu  which should open up SQL import and Export Wizard. You can save it as package and deploy it under the SSIS catalog and run as scheduled job too.

**Alternative solution 4**

Write an SSIS package to get data from SQL server and put into Excel.